# How to add prefix to section names and create space in table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I would like to add the prefix "Appendix" to appendix sections such that it appears in a table of contents. However, whenever I add this prefix using the `\renewcommand` command, the table of contents overlaps the prefix and the section names. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,oneside,letterpaper,onecolumn]{report}  
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables 
\cleardoublepage

\clearpage
\chapter{Section 1}

XYZ

\begin{subappendices}    
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix 1.\arabic{section}}

\section{Part 1}
XYZ 

\section{Part 2}
XYZ

\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to add this but generate the appropriate spacing? Thanks.

THE ANSWER IS:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,oneside,letterpaper,onecolumn]{report}  
\usepackage[titletoc, toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables 
\cleardoublepage

\clearpage
\chapter{Section 1}

XYZ

\begin{subappendices}    
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix 1.\arabic{section}}

\section{Part 1}
XYZ 

\section{Part 2}
XYZ

\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try the package option `titletoc`

Comment: The `tocloft` package can help, too.

Comment: @coding_heart: You can make a self-answer and self-accept, this way the question is 'closed'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments