# add prefix to headline and reserve enough space in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

my question is basically a follow-up on [Adding a Prefix to Section Title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414647/adding-a-prefix-to-section-title), where the question is how to add an arbitrary prefix to the number that appears before a headline/section.

My follow-up question is: What do I need to do in order to ensure that the TOC has enough space so that the prefix-number does not overlap with the headline?

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Some Prefix~\arabic{section}:}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents  

  \section{First Headline}
  Some text.

  \section{Second Headline}
  More text!

  \section{Third Headline}
  And so on...  

\end{document}
```

**Without** the second line (i.e., the renewcommand) the result looks as expected:

[image]

**With** the renewcommand, the sections themselve appear correct (btw: this is is the solution to the question linked above), but the text in the TOC overlaps:

[image]

Thus,

**Question**: What do I need to do to have enough space before the actual headline begins in the toc?

Comment: Just fyi: My question seems highly related to [How to add prefix to section names and create space in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302016/how-to-add-prefix-to-section-names-and-create-space-in-table-of-contents), but the question and answer is specific to an appendix, which is not the case for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `koma` class, you can use `tocbasic` to format
your toc. The following should work without a `koma` class as well, if
you load `tocbasic` explicitly (`usepackage{tocbasic}`). You can choose
two different approaches. In general I'd recommend you to check out the
`koma` manual ([English](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) or [German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf)).

## Increase the space for the section number (+ prefix)

To increase the space left of the section name in toc, you can do the
following:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=8em]{tocline}{section}
```

This makes all section names start at the same position, `8em` from the left.

## Dynamic width depending on length of prefix + number

Alternatively, you can put the section names in toc just after the longest
number (+prefix) with

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=true]{tocline}{section}
```

You could add `numsep=1em` to the arguments to set the space between
the number and name to a different value:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=true,
                      numsep=1em,
]{tocline}{section}
```

## Both in a MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Some Prefix~%
  \if\arabic{section}1Ooone\else
    \if\arabic{section}2Two\else%
      \if\arabic{section}33%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi:}

% Try *one* of the following styles. They add up!
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=true,
                      numsep=1em,
]{tocline}{section}

%\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=10em]{tocline}{section}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents  

  \section{First Headline}
  Some text.

  \section{Second Headline}
  More text!

  \section{Third Headline}
  And so on...  

\end{document}
```

I changed the prefix in length, to show the effect of `dynnumwidth`.

First style, with `dynnumwidth`:

[image: result1]

Second style, fixed:

[image: result2]